# youtube streaming api time zone

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

we use Youtube API to schedule streaming on a website we create. It works fine except that we don't have the correct time zone even if we respect time format in ISO 8601, it steel is the california time zone (we are in France).

Any thought ?

Thanks

J

Comment: Can you please provide the format for `scheduled start time`? Here's a sample of standard ISO format: **YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ**

Comment: Hi @d.datul1990 thanks for your comment and here is the exact format we use "start_time": "2012-11-25T12:00:00Z"